# How do you specify joint location in SDF 1.0

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I'm putting together an arm manipulator
My urdf model worked well with rvis and all the joints worked as expected and the kinematics were correct.
However I've been trying to convert to SDF1.0 format in order to use plugins but my kinematics are all odd. The joints still have the  tag specified (in order to correctly locate the joint) but even when I modify the pose (which I'm taking to be  "x y z r p y", though the documentation is pretty scarce) value, it doesn't change the positioning of the joint.

Any help for converting these files or helping me understand how kinematics are specified in sdf would be great.

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48630/how-do-you-specify-joint-location-in-sdf-1.0/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, got this one to work.

The Joint location is given by the child link origin which is specified as part of the "link " element at the root level. This joint origin needs to be specified in terms of the model origin (my model origin was at 0 0 0 0 0 0) so it could also be the global origin. Therefore you need to work out the positions of the joints initially in this coordinate frame. And it seems to work.

On a side note, this specifying joint locations in this manner is unconventional. The original urdf method of locating the joint in terms of the parent link in the parent links frame is far more conventional and widely used. It requires a lot less initial calculation to boot.

Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aleena_infinitynbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/44647/aleena_infinitynbeyond/) on 2020-06-15**:
I was facing a similar problem, when I converted my urdf ROS file to an sdf file for using my manipulator model in Gazebo. Here is my problem
https://answers.ros.org/question/354852/overlapping-sdf-model-of-kinova-arm/?comment=354882#post-id-354882
@PeterMilani can you please help?